# Float right and width of inline-block element

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/4zJyw/1/

In all major browsers, except of IE7, the example works as expected - the parent div has total width of 100px, but in IE7 in some reason it stretches for all width.

And this happens only if `v` element has `float: right`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could sort this out was to use `position:relative` on the parent, and `position:absolute; right:0` on the div with the 'v' inside it.